# Symfony2 Config TreeBuilder validation of array values in YML

Tags: php, validation, symfony, configuration

I've got a configuration in YML, that looks like this :

```
foobar_template:
    templates:
        homepage:
            name: "Homepage template"
            regions: ["top", "main", "left", "bottom"]
            layout:
              - [ { region: "top", colspan: 4 } ]
              - [ { region: "left" }, { region: "main", colspan: 3 } ]
              - [ { region: "bottom", colspan: 4 } ]

        subpage:
            name: "Subpage template"
            regions: ["top", "main"]
            layout:
              - [ { region: "top", colspan: 4 } ]
              - [ { region: "main", colspan: 4 } ]
```

I've been trying to make sure that this configuration is defined according to specifications, but seem to be unable to make sure that the layout section contains entries that at least define one region. Currently my Configuration.php contains the following :

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('foobar_template');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('templates')
                    ->useAttributeAsKey('template')
                    ->prototype('array')
                        ->children()
                            ->scalarNode('name')->end()
                            ->arrayNode('regions')
                                ->isRequired()
                                ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                                ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                            ->end()
                            ->append($this->addLayoutNode())
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }

    public function addLayoutNode()
    {
        $builder = new TreeBuilder();
        $node = $builder->root('layout');

        $node
            ->isRequired()
            ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
            ->prototype('array')
                ->prototype('variable')->end()
            ->end();

        return $node;
    }
}
```

But I would really like to test that the layout blocks specified contain a region (ie. a snippet containing at least `- [{ region: <region_name> }]`, so what should I use instead of `->prototype('variable')->end()` in addLayoutNode() to actually perform this test? I've tried multiple things, but always run into an InvalidDefinitionException or InvalidConfigurationException when trying to do this. Anyone got an idea on how to test the above in Configuration? (I currently do some sanity checks in the load of the bundle Extension, but it would be cleaner if the Configuration could check this).

Answer (score -2):

You can use a ConfigurationProccesor: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/config/definition.html#processing-configuration-values
or a CompilerPass for the more complex config.